# exporting XML to CSV

Tags: xml, excel, powershell, csv

I have the code below to export XML to CSV format. The code is just generating empty CSV files with no content. Any Idea how I might get the code to work?

```psh
$in_root = "C:\Temp\xml"
$out_root = "C:\Temp\csv"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $in_root -File

foreach ($file in $files) {
  $xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw)
  $props = @{}
  foreach ($item in $xml.table.row.col) {
    $props[$item.name] = $item."#text"
  }

  [PSCustomObject]$props |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path (Join-Path -Path $out_root -ChildPath "$($file.BaseName).csv")
}
```

Here is the sample XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Inbound.Schema0">
  <BookAttribute>
    <MainTitle>April 2010: The United States Constitution by United States</MainTitle>
    <Courtesy_of> berg DVD - April 2010</Courtesy_of>
    <Title_Heading>The United States Constitution by United States</Title_Heading>
    <caption>Bibliographic Record</caption>
    <Firstauths>United States</Firstauths>
    <Firsttitls>The United States Constitution</Firsttitls>
    <Naturalsprache>English</Naturalsprache>
    <FirstLoolassC>JK: Political science: Political inst. and pub. Admin.: United States</FirstLoolassC>
    <Onesobject>United States</Onesobject>
    <Twosobject>Government</Twosobject>
    <Etxextnumber>5</Etxextnumber>
    <Releasedate>1975-12-01</Releasedate>
    <Copyrighttus>Not copyrighted in the United States.</Copyrighttus>
    <Baseddirectory>/etext90</Baseddirectory>
    <Newlinknumber>etext90</Newlinknumber>
  </BookAttribute>
</ns0:Root>
```

The desired output will just be semicolon-seperated columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing your XML data doesn't have elements `table`, `row`, or `col`, so `$xml.table.row.col` won't work. Try creating custom objects from the child nodes of your `<BookAttribute>` nodes:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//BookAttribute') | ForEach-Object {
  $o = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject
  $_.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object {
    $o | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.'#text'
  }
  $o
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

Comment: Dear Wiechers. Is there any good reason.. why you downgrade the Question? Can you please remove your downgrade. Even a Genius like Einstien, have to learn how to walk.

Comment: The down vote may be due to the question being incomplete.  What language are you using?